Imbue CARBS warning hyperparameter tuning
For a few iteration I got no warning but then it pops out telling me that
No Candidates found, choosing at random"
Here is the warning :
carbs.carbs:suggest:192 - Got error generating candidate linalg.cholesky: The factorization could not be completed because the input is not positive-definite (the leading minor of order 16 is not positive-definite).
Could you please help me thank you in advance.
